# Winston only logs either warnings or errors

Tags: logging, winston, logentries

I have a fairly straight forward winston setup, where I add 3 transports to a custom logger:

```
import winston from 'winston';
import Logentries from 'winston-logentries';

const logger = new (winston.Logger)();

logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
  name: 'info-console',
  level: 'info',
  prettyPrint: true,
  colorize: true,
  silent: false,
  timestamp: false,
});

logger.add(winston.transports.File, {
  name: 'error-file',
  prettyPrint: false,
  level: 'warn',
  silent: false,
  colorize: false,
  timestamp: true,
  filename: `${__dirname}/../logs/error.log`,
  maxsize: 40000,
  maxFiles: 10,
  json: false,
});

logger.add(winston.transports.Logentries, {
  token: '--secret--',
  level: 'warn',
});

export default logger;
```

Logging is really unreliable though. In the past, I had an issue with the file logger either logging only warnings or errors dending on the level I set for that transport (and not, as expected logging errors *and* warnings when I set my level to warn). Also sometimes it would just not log anything, but that seems to be a different story. Back then I did not have the third transport yet (`Logentries`), now the file logger is better, apart from not logging anything sometimes, but `Logentries` has the same behavior as the file logger back then, only logging the specific level set to it.

Comment: You need to specify log levels, as winston uses different levels, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945706/logentries-with-winston-in-not-capturing-error-debug