# Logentries with Winston in not capturing ERROR, DEBUG

Tags: node.js, winston, logentries

I am using Winston 3.1.0 in my NodeJS app, together with Logentries le_node 1.8.0.

Logentries is only capturing only INFO, DEBUG nor ERROR nor DEBUG.

I am using also Console & File transports, and those are logged correctly.

Any idea why LE is only capturing info, debug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by defining `levels` in constructor:
[image]

Comment: Dude you are a lifesaver. thanks so much. wonder why this happens